# CSS simulate scrollbar height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an huge list that in first I want to show the first x items. When the user is scrolling, I want to append more items to the list.

My problem is that I need to simulate the scrollbar to be as like the total items are already on the list.

How can I accomplish this?

```js
    const container = document.querySelector("section");
    const arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
     arr.push(`
        <div class="msg">msg</div>
      `)
    }

    container.innerHTML = arr.join("");
```

```css
section {
 width: 300px;
 height: 3000px; // This is for example the total height
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.msg {
 padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

My list is also dynamic.

Comment: get the max number of items, then calculate the height and assign it with jquery. Then just take care to load the items before it reach that part of the website.

Comment: But I don't have scrollbar now because I don't have overflow. I need to simulate scrollbar

Comment: keep overflow:auto .. Hope it will work .

Comment: again, get the number of items from the database (not from the html) and calculate the total height (font-size+margins+padding) and assign it to the container. that should give you the scrollbar.

Comment: If you have enough space the scrollbar will not show

Comment: You can add an answer with example please?